# SQL Server Select last 4 weeks from now and same period from last year only

Tags: sql-server, date

I have tried searching for a soln to this but have been unable yet to find one.

I need to select the last 4 weeks of data from todays date which is not the issue as I just do a `date >= Dateadd(mm, -1, getdate())`. However I also want the same 4 weeks of data from the previous year. But I dont want (for example) June 1-30 2010 and June 1-30 2011, I would need

June 30th (thursday) 2011 and 4 weeks prior AND July 1st and four weeks prior as july 1st was the thursday in the same week from the prev year.

so 8 weeks of data would be returned.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What logic are you using to select `6/30/2011` instead of `7/7/2011`?

Comment: @JNK It's `7/1/2010` and if you subtract 52 weeks from `6/30/2011` you get `7/1/2010`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use some more `DATEADD()` goodness to go back to the previous year:

```
where theDate >= DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())    
OR
    (theDate <= DATEADD(week,-52,convert(datetime,GETDATE()))
     and
     theDate >= DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(week,-52,convert(datetime,GETDATE()))))
```

Subtracting 52 weeks from 6/30/2011 returns 7/1/2010 as you requested... Then using your original subtraction of 1 month from there for the lower bound.

You could also switch the whole thing to use weeks...

```
where theDate >= DATEADD(week, -4, GETDATE())    
OR
    (theDate <= DATEADD(week,-52,convert(datetime,GETDATE()))
     and
     theDate >= DATEADD(week,-56,convert(datetime,GETDATE())))
```

Comment: What if I wanted to get the last 12 weeks instead of 4 weeks?

Comment: Then use the second example, change -4 to -12, -56 to -64.

Answer (score 0):

you may do a serial of ORed BETWEEN conditions:

```
select
  ...
from
  ...
where
  1=1
  or date between Dateadd(mm, -2, getdate()) and Dateadd(mm, -1, getdate())
  or date between Dateadd(mm, -11, getdate()) and Dateadd(mm, -10, getdate())
order by
  date
```

did i understand right?

Comment: This doesn't appear to handle the week issue the op mentioned, selecting 4 weeks ending 6/30/2011, and 4 weeks ending 7/1/2010.

Answer (score 0):

Last four weeks sales data:

```sql
with cte as (
    select case when row_number() OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(wk,CreatedDate) DESC) = 2 then 'last 1st Week'
                when row_number() OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(wk,CreatedDate) DESC) = 3 then 'last 2nd Week'
                when row_number() OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(wk,CreatedDate) DESC) = 4 then 'last 3rd Week'
                when row_number() OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(wk,CreatedDate) DESC) = 5 then 'last 4th Week'  
                else 'last 5th plusweek'
           end as weeks,
    sum(amt) as week_wise_sale,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(wk,CreatedDate) DESC) AS [row number]
    from samt 
    group by DATEPART(wk,CreatedDate)
) select * from cte where [ROW NUMBER] > 1
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include an explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful to those who come across the same issue later on.